# Selenium IDE, how to improve this Target (to use the name of the choise instead of the position)

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

here's my case:

After recording some steps i can see that clicking on a the 6th item in a list (which shows 'Boeken' on the screen) resulted in this command:

```
command: click
target: //div[@id='syi-categories-l1']/ul/li[6]
value: (empty)
```

If I use 'Find', next to 'Target', it highlights this value (yellow) and it works perfectly.
However, the value I selected is indeed the 6th value, but I am trying to change this so it doesn't select the 6th value, but the value 'Boeken', regardless of its position.
Is there a way to change the Target to do this?
If i use the selector, the value 'Boeken' says the following:

```
<li class="item active" data-val="201" data-ga-track-page-view-on-click="/SYI/SELECTCATEGORY/201_boeken">Boeken</li>
```

Comment: Have you seen the documentation? http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#location-strategies

Comment: Hi SiKing, thanks for improving the questing and pointing towards the right documentation. I did read about the different ways to locate the object, but in this specific case I seem not to be able to find the way to point to this item using the value 'Boeken'. I will leave it for now, there is still a lot to learn for me, and this was just one of the question that raised, i will keep on reading and learning and will give it a new try in the near future. Thanks for your help!